# GDB step by step debugging of two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb

I have a c++ program running two threads. thread A and thread B. is there a way to do step by step debugging of both threads in GDB? steps should be something like this:

1. Stop Threads A & B
2. Switch to thread A. continue one step.
3. Switch to thread B. continue two steps.

Comment: You should probably read the GDB manual, specifically https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/All_002dStop-Mode.html#All_002dStop-Mode and https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html#Threads

Comment: `set scheduler-locking` to `on` or `step` might work. You aren't looking to single step all the threads, AFAICT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the gdb commands   "info threads" to see all the threads of the process, then use command "thread thread-id"  top switch to whichever thread you want.